# Adjusting height for modals

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

This plugin is installed on my company's site and I want to have dynamic height.  I think this code will do the trick.

```
   $.modal(data,
{
  minWidth: 400,
  onShow: function(dialog){
    //изменение размеров контейнера по размеру контена
    dialog.container.css({"height":"auto","width":"auto"});
  }
});
```

Current state question: Does there need to be individual height attribute between every individual modal or can you adjust the height via the plugin for all modals?

Comment: You can adjust it for all the modals, just place the code of the configuration in your index.html file and it will affect all the modals you create. Check out the options for the defaults modal here https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal Just add a custom class with the height you want

Comment: Thank you.  Sub question:  If there are existing modals that are using a plugin but some other developer changed each one differently, would changing the base file "index.html" location override all the other modals?

Comment: No, because you're just changing the default settings of the modal, the other developers would override those settings with their own

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust it for all the modals, just place the code of the configuration in your index.html file and it will affect all the modals you create. Check out the options for the defaults modal here github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal Just add a custom class with the height you want